# Regex : replace spaces in a file but only target a particular tag (href)

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, sublimetext3

I want to change spaces in the file but only within href="     " tag. The remaining file should not be affected. Is there a way to do it directly in regex, lets say Visual Studio studio, or Sublime or any other editor of your choice

```
<li><a target="_blank" href="/img/closed-sales/Anderson Ocn Club
2010.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer">Anderson Ocean Club 2010</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="/img/closed-sales/Anderson ceanClub 2011.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer">Anderson</a></li>
```

I have tried `href="/.*"` which basically matches href="" but I need to replaced spaces and other characters such as @ sign in it. [Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/W8CGuT/1)

Comment: `Visual Studio studio` or `Visual Studio Code`? What have you tried, BTW?

Comment: BTW, it is possible in Sublime Text, Notepad++.

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Comment: Added @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ or SublimeText, you may leverage the `\G` construct to match substrings starting from the end of the preceding match thus limiting search and replace to a specific text portion between *different* delimiters. In your case, the attribute values are enclosed with `"`, so you may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|href="/)[^\s"]*\K\s
```

and replace with any char(s) you need. If the `\K` is not supported use

```
(\G(?!^)|href="/)([^\s"]*)\s
```

and replace with `$1$2[some new text]`. The difference between this and the previous patterns is that the text matched with `(\G(?!^)|href="/)` and `([^\s"]*)`  is also *captured* into a group, and the `$1` and `$2` are corresponding placeholders ([numbered replacement backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)) that refer to the texts captured with those [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

In Visual Studio, you may use `(?<=href="/[^"]*?)\s` instead.

See [this **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fFYnr5/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|href="/)` - start of the preceding match or `href="/` substring
- `[^\s"]*` - 0 or more chars other than `"` and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator that removes all text matched so far from the match buffer
- `\s` - a whitespace char.

Sublime Text 3 (Windows):

[image]

Notepad++:

[image]

Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Nice. But this unfortunately did not work in sublime. I am on mac, does not have notepad++.

Comment: @HammadKhan Try `(\G(?!^)|href="/)([^\s"]*)\s` to replace with `$1$2+`. Probably, the `\K` construct is not recognized.

Comment: Yes this  last one worked in sublime. Can you explain $1$2+ a bit in answer. Seems a little complicated. I know $1 is group and group 2 but still

Comment: @HammadKhan I added some more description with relevant documentation links.